# Mule ESB non production version

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Do we have anon-production version for mulesoft. Basically we are performing a poC on AWS and are using mulesoft as middleware. Is there a developer version of mulesoft which we can deploy?

Comment: There is a mule runtime community edition available, here is the link https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

Comment: Thanks. Will there be any functionality that will not be available in this edition vs the licensed version?

Comment: Here is comparison matrix for community vs enterprise https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise

Answer (score 1):

ssanrao helped. There is a community edition of mule which can be used for development purposes. Thanks ssanrao for the quick help

Answer (score 1):

In the community version you won't get access for the two important features i.e Data weave and batch job .
Data weave is the most powerful transformer using which you can easily transform very complex data types to your desired data type without any hassle.You won't get the actual flavor of mule.